# Not sure what PRJ_FILE_STATE_HYDRATED_PLACEHOLDER documentation means

Tags: projfs

I started working with Projected File system, but I'm not sure if I read the documentation correctly. `PRJ_FILE_STATE_HYDRATED_PLACEHOLDER`.
says

> The item is a hydrated placeholder, i.e., the item's **content** has been written to disk.

For me this sounds like the file content (not the metadata) was written to disk.
However there is also `PRJ_FILE_STATE_FULL` which also sounds like the complete data (metadata + file content) is cached.

I would asume that `PRJ_FILE_STATE_HYDRATED_PLACEHOLDER` actually means

> [...] the item's **metadata** has been written to dist.

Can someone confirm this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another part in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/projfs/projected-file-system#cache-state-in-the-virtualization-root) that was more detailed:

> Hydrated placeholder
>
> For files: The file’s content and metadata have been cached to the disk. Also referred to as a "partial file".
>
> For directories: A directory that was created on disk as a placeholder never becomes a hydrated placeholder directory. This allows the provider to add or remove items from the directory in its backing store and have those changes be reflected in the local cache.